# Why does cin.rdbuf()->sbumpc() ask me for input just one time in a loop?

Tags: c++

This is an example of the c++ reference page of

- std::basic_streambuf::sputbackc

and i am trying to find:

> Why does " ch = pbuf->sbumpc() " ask me for input just one time in a loop and not in every cycle?

here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout, std::streambuf, std::streamsize
  int main () {
    char ch;
    std::streambuf * pbuf = std::cin.rdbuf();

    std::cout << "Please, enter some letters and then a number: ";
    do {
      ch = pbuf->sbumpc();           //why this line ask an input just once in all the loop?

      if ( (ch>='0') && (ch <='9') )
      {
        pbuf->sputbackc (ch);
        long n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << "You entered number " << n << '\n';
        break;
      }
    } while ( ch != std::streambuf::traits_type::eof() );

    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you enter `LL10`.  `pbuf->sbumpc();` reads one character from the stream. So it reads in `L`.  Since that is not between 0 and 9 we loop again.  `L10` is still in the buffer so we read in `L` again.  Again it it not in the range so we loop again.  Now the buffer just has `10` in it.  We read in the `1` and since it is in the range we put it back, read in the buffer using `std::cin >> n;` and then `break` out of the loop.  That is why you only have to enter input once.  Had you only inputted `LL` it would wait for you to enter more.